# Добавить несколько лет к дате в строке

Tags: java

Есть `String lastyear` в которой лежит значение `2015`;
Нужно к ней добавить 10 лет, чтобы получить в итоге:

```
lastyear="2025";
```

Как сделать наиболее просто и красиво?

Answer (score 2):

Обычный вариант: распарсить, сложить и обратно загнать в String

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String year = "2015";
    int futureYear = Integer.parseInt(year) + 10;
    String newYear = String.valueOf(futureYear);
    System.out.println(newYear);
}
```

Есть еще вариант с BigDecimal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String year = "2015";
    BigDecimal decimalYear = new BigDecimal(year);
    BigDecimal tenYear = new BigDecimal(10);
    String newYear = decimalYear.add(tenYear).toString();
    System.out.println(newYear);
}
```